# Filling entire screen horizontally with 3 views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to fill entire screen horizontally with 3 views. I want all of them to be of equal size. If I am entering the value of their width in dp manually either one of them goes bigger than other or on changing device it doesn't fill the screen on large one. Whats the correct approach to do it?
[image: What I want]

Comment: create a relative layout and in this create a linear layout with orentation horizontal also give weight 1 to each buttons in linear layout

Comment: and don't forget to give the parent linear layout weight sum = 3.

Comment: @raj It's working thank you. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @praneethkumar Thanks, really appreciate it. :)

Comment: did you give linear layout weight match parent? please post your layout code!

Comment: @praneethkumar I just did a silly mistake. Thanks its working now.

Comment: @Bugdroid Happy if I helped you! may I know what is that 'silly mistake'?

Comment: @praneethkumar surely, I added android:weight instead of android:layout_weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parent layout with "fill_parent" width property and then give layout_weight="1" for each of the view.

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this code

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Test" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Test" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Test" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment, but I don't have enough rep. So I'm posting this as an answer. Are you using a horizontal `LinearLayout` to wrap these three? If yes, have you tried using the attribute `android:layout_weight`? If you have not, set `android:layout_weight="1"` for all of these views in your layout XML. This should place these views equally. It would be more helpful if you could post your XML code, though.

Comment: now you can comment .. :)  :) you give right ans but  proper required explanation which person post question they dont know about weight right so if you write this then they will not understand. because if they know about weight then he will not post question here.. right.? miss :)

Comment: @VishalHalani Thank you. :) I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

**you can do like this i just place button you write other componants also**

```
 <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Test" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Test" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Test" />

</LinearLayout>
```